# Finding the derivative of a complicated vector to scalar function

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, optimization, vector-analysis, least-squares

Given a set of $N$ lines $\mathbf{L}$, each of which is defined by a point $\mathbf{a}$ and the unit vector direction it points in $\hat{\mathbf{d}}$, I have the following function:

$$
C = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i \in L}\| \mathbf{c} - \mathbf{a_i} \|^2 - [(\mathbf{c} -\mathbf{a_i})\cdot \mathbf{\hat d_i}]^2
$$

You make recognize this as the sum of the squared distances from a point $\mathbf{c}$ to a set of lines.

I want to solve for $\frac{\partial C}{\partial \mathbf{a_j}}$ and $\frac{\partial C}{\partial \mathbf{\hat{d_j}}}$, under the constraint that $\frac{\partial C}{\partial\mathbf{c}} = 0$

I am having trouble solving for these partial derivatives because $\mathbf{c}$ can't be treated as a constant due to the fact that it is a function of all of the $\mathbf{a_i}$ and $\mathbf{\hat{h_i}}$ describing the lines in $\mathbf{L}$.

If it helps, I arrived at this equation trying to solve the following problem:

"If a set of lines $\mathbf{L}$, each of which is defined by a point $\mathbf{a}$ and the unit vector direction it points in $\hat{\mathbf{d}}$, do not intersect, how does the minimum distance between all of the lines change as $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{\hat{d}}$ are changed? The minimum distance between all of the $N$ lines is defined as the average distance from the point $\mathbf{c}$, where $\mathbf{c}$ is the point that has the least distance to all of the $N$ lines."

What I'm really trying to figure out is a measure of how "close" a set of lines are to intersecting perfectly, and how changing the line parameters slightly affects that "closeness."

If there is any better way to solve this problem than what I have proposed, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me what $\frac{\partial C}{\partial \mathbf{a_j}}$ even *means*.

Comment: @Nick $\frac{\partial C}{\partial \mathbf{a_j}}$ describes how the scalar value of $C$ changes if one of the components, $\mathbf{a_j}$, of one of the lines in $\mathbf{L}$ changes slightly.

Comment: I don't understand: if the lines don't intersect, then vector $\hat{\mathbf{d}}$ should be the same for all lines (apart a possible sign change). And then, what does "the point that has the least distance to all of the $N$ lines" mean? Should I minimize the sum of the distances of ${\mathbf{c}}$ from the lines? Or the sum of their squares (as you seem to imply)? Or something else?

Comment: The vector $\mathbf{\hat{d}}$ can be different for every line even if the lines don't intersect; the lines can be skew. Yes, minimize the sum of the squares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be the matrix whose columns are the $\{a_k\}$ vectors, and $D$ be the matrix whose columns are $\{d_k\}$.

Next define a matrix $$C=\sum_k ce_k^T$$ all of whose columns are equal to the vector $c$.

Finally define the matrix $M=(A-C)$.

Given the standard basis vectors $\{e_k\}$ we can write 
$$ \eqalign {
 a_k &= Ae_k, &\,\,\,\,d_k = De_k, &\,\,\,\,(a_k-c) = Me_k \cr
} $$

Since $C$ has been used to represent a matrix, let's use the symbol $L$ to represent the cost function (multiplied by $N$). Let's write it in terms of the above matrices and find its differential
$$ \eqalign {
L &= \sum_k Me_k:Me_k - (Me_ke_k^TD^T)^T:(Me_ke_k^TD^T) \cr\cr
dL
 &= 2\,\sum_k Me_k:dM\,e_k - (Me_ke_k^TD^T)^T:d(Me_ke_k^TD^T) \cr
 &= 2\,\sum_k ME_{kk}:dM - (DE_{kk}M^T):(dM\,E_{kk}D^T+ME_{kk}\,dD^T) \cr
 &= 2\,\sum_k (ME_{kk}- DE_{kk}M^TDE_{kk}):dM - (E_{kk}M^TDE_{kk}M^T):dD^T \cr
 &= 2\,\sum_k (ME_{kk}- DE_{kk}M^TDE_{kk}):(dA-dC) - (ME_{kk}D^TME_{kk}):dD \cr
} $$ where the colons represent the double-contraction product, i.e.
$$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
From the differential expression we can see that
$$ \eqalign {
\frac{\partial L}{\partial A} =
-\frac{\partial L}{\partial C} =
 0 \cr
} $$
by virtue of the constraint.

This leaves us with the gradient wrt $D$ as the only non-zero term 
$$ \eqalign {
\frac{\partial L}{\partial D} &= -2\,\sum_kMe_ke_k^TD^TMe_ke_k^T \cr
\frac{\partial L}{\partial d_j}
 &= -2\,Me_jd_j^TMe_j \cr
 &= 2\,(c-a_j)d_j^T(a_j-c) \cr
} $$
To recover your original cost function, divide these expressions by $N$.

Comment: Intuitively, I can't see how $\frac{\partial L}{\partial A}$ could possible equal zero. If an element of $A$ is changed, then certainly the closest point to all of the lines would move, changing the loss function right?

Comment: Normally, neither $\frac{\partial L}{\partial C}$ nor $\frac{\partial L}{\partial A}$ would equal zero. But in the problem statement, you specified that the former is constrained to be zero. The above derivation indicates that the two gradients are identical (except for the sign). So it is the _constraint_ that forces this particular gradient to zero.

Comment: Fascinating, thanks!